# Magento 2. How to Hide Price for multi Price products

Tags: magento2, product, frontend

I'm Hiding Price using **Plugin**. the Plugin is Hiding price for every product except the multi value products. My code is

> Vender/Module/Plugin/Price.php

```
<?php

namespace Vender\Module\Plugin;

class Price
{
function afterToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, $result)
 {
return " ";
}
}
```

> Vender/Module/etc/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">

        <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
            <plugin name="price_hide" type="Vender\Module\Plugin\Price"/>        
        </type>
</config>
```

For other **Product** it shows like 
[image]

and for the **Multi Price Products** it shows like
[image]

Now How to hide price of multi price product using **Plugin**.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Below Code is working for me:

[image]

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">    
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox">
        <plugin name="price_hide" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Price" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>        
    </type>
</config>
```

> Vendor\Module\Plugin\Price.php

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

    class Price
    {
        function aroundToHtml(\Magento\Catalog\Pricing\Render\FinalPriceBox $subject, callable $proceed) {         
                return '';
        }
    }
```

Comment: The Only issue I'm getting now is that the price is hidden everywhere and if I return some text then it doesn't return anything just hide the price everywhere